# Angular 8: Render child component after data required is fetched through HTTP call

Tags: angular

In my AppComponent template, I have 3 child components - HeaderComponent, MenuComponent, ContentComponent. The data for child component - MenuComponent is dynamically loaded through an HTTP request. If I make the HTTP call through the service in ngOnInit or constructor of the component, the data is not loaded and the view has no data to render. I want to wait for the data for menu to return as response after I make the HTTP call, and then render the MenuComponent with the data.

I am new to Angular, it would be really great if someone could propose a solution.

app.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-menu></app-menu>
    <app-content></app-content>
</div>
```

menu.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MainMenuService } from "main-menu.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  mainMenuData;

  constructor(public menuService: MainMenuService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mainMenuData = this.menuService.getDataforMenu();
  }
}
```

menu.component.html

```
<nav>
    <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let mainMenu of mainMenuData">
                <a class="main-menu" href="{{ mainMenu.href }}">{{ mainMenu.name }}</a>
          </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

main-menu.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MainMenuService {
  menu;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getDataforMenu() {
    this.httpClient.get(URL).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        return response;
      },
      (error: any) => {

      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Update your html file like

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-menu *ngIf="isMenuDataLoaded"></app-menu>
    <app-content *ngIf="isContentDataLoaded"></app-content>
</div>
```

Then add variables in your ts file, whose default value will be false and set it true when you data from API

Like

```
isMenuDataLoaded = false;
isContentDataLoaded = false;

ngOnInit() {
   // your API call

  this.menuService.getDataforMenu().subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
         this.mainMenuData = response;
         this.isMenuDataLoaded = true;
      },
         (error: any) => {

     }
}
```

Also you need to update your service

```
getDataforMenu() {
   return this.httpClient.get(URL);
}
```

This will make sure that and inform angular load the component when the data is available.

Note I have used boolean, just for simplicity. If you are getting data as array you can check with `.length` property also

Comment: Also pass `mainMenuData` as an input to your component

Comment: HI Kenny, if I am to pass mainMenuData as an input to my MenuComponent then I should make the HTTP call from AppComponent right?

Comment: @NHG Yes. If you want to pass it as a input.

Comment: But if the resposnse of that http call only contains data which related to specific component then make a call from that child component

Comment: Always keep in mind, if an API has a data which is useful to parent and child component then make a call from parent component and pass data to the child component as an input. But if an API has a data which is only useful to child component then make a call from child component itself. As in this case it doesn't make any sense to get data in parent and pass it as an Input